# Contact Form 7 Plugin to send mail to different user according to mail content

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am creating a plugin which hooks Contact form 7 before sending the mail the plug-in will check the message content and decide on which email the message should go. My Plugin works fine but due to this the Contact form 7 validation is not working. Whenever I am sending message the spinner keeps on rotating but mail is sending properly. Only success or validation message is not working.

```
<?php
   /*
   Plugin Name: Email Filteration
   Plugin URI: http://my-awesomeness-emporium.com
   Description: a plugin to filter your message type
   Version: 1.0
   Author: Himanshu
   Author URI: http://mrtotallyawesome.com
   License: GPL2
   */
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once ('email-filter-menu.php');
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_newpage' );
function register_newpage()
{
add_menu_page('Email Filter', 'Email Filter', 'administrator', 'custompage', 'user_input_data');
} 

add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'cf7sr_verify_email_filter' );
    function cf7sr_verify_email_filter( $cf7 )
    {
        $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
        $data = $submission->get_posted_data();

        $user_name_data=get_option('EF_user_name_field');
        $user_phone_data=get_option('EF_user_phone_field');
        $user_subject_data=get_option('EF_user_subject_field');
        $user_message_var=get_option('EF_user_message_field');
        $user_f_word=get_option('EF_user_filter_words');
        $words=explode(",",$user_f_word);
        $message=$data[$user_message_var];
        $name_field=$data[$user_name_data];
        $phone_field=$data[$user_phone_data];
        $subject_field=$data[$user_subject_data];
        $string_union=$message." ".$name_field." ".$phone_field." ".$subject_field;
        // $array_message=array("seo", "web");
        // $words=array("seo", "responsive");
        $array_message=preg_split("/( |,)/", $string_union);
        $result=array_intersect(array_map('strtolower',$array_message), array_map('strtolower',$words));
        if($result){
            $to ='writercontent2017@gmail.com';
            $subject = "Message from plugins";
            $headerss = 'From: himanshucoolindia@gmail.com';
            $sent = wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headerss);

            $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'From: <himanshucoolindia@gmail>' . "\r\n";
            mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

            $submission->skip_mail = true;
            //add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_response_output', 'wpse_form_response_output', 10, 4 );


                $wpcf7 = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();
                $wpcf7->skip_mail = true;
                add_filter( 'wpcf7_skip_mail',  '__return_true' );
                add_filter( 'wpcf7_load_js', '__return_false' );
                add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_response_output', 'wpse_form_response_output', 10, 4 );
        }

    }

    function wpse_form_response_output( $output, $class, $content, $object )
    {
        return sprintf(
            '<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none wpcf7-mail-sent-ng" 
                role="alert" style="display: block;">%s</div>',
            __( 'SOAP ERROR - Mail not sent!' )
        );
    }

?>
```

Here I have includes email-filter-menu.php file if I comment this then Email-validation starts working but Success message is not showing.

Comment: It seems to me that it's using AJAX and never getting a proper response back so it doesn't know to terminate the never ending circle. I don't know off the top of my head what the exact solution is but that should be a step in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you @Difster

Comment: I don't know why someone down-voted you, it was a perfectly reasonable question.